# HealthVault app not supported in your location

Tags: healthvault

I have created an demo application using healthvault sdk application manager and registered the application on healthvault ppe.when i run the application its runs perfectly and fetches and displays data from healthvault.

I have used same application ID and certificate for another application and when i try to run the 2nd application its gives following error/message

We're sorry. MyHealthVaultDemo is not supported in your location.
"You won't be able to use MyHealthVaultDemo because of an account location mismatch with this app. "

can anyone help me what is wrong with the 2nd  application which is using registered AppID ,which works fine for the first application..
Thanks

Comment: Why not speak with microsoft support?

Comment: I have already posted question on healthvault developer forum ..still awaiting reply

Comment: There are 28 questions regarding healthvault on SO not sure you will get an answer here, good luck though.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that the certificate that you are re-using is setup for an application that is restricted to a particular HealthVault instance which isn't accessible from your geographical location.

The following links provide detail on the available instances:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/healthvault/healthvault-global-architecture.aspx

I'd recommend using the HealthVault Application Manager (available as part of the .NET Sdk) to generate a new certificate and application Id.

Alternatively, if you're not using the .NET Sdk, you could setup a new application directly via the Application Configuration Center (https://config.healthvault-ppe.com)